# Is There DataGrids open sources for Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Is there any DataGrids open sources for Silverlight 5.0, that supports sorting and filtering?
I've worked with DevExpress (.NET Library) and I faced many problems with binding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid in Silverlight Toolkit supports sorting. Filtering can be done if you bind to a PagedCollectionView or a DomainDataSource. Sources are available [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/88660).